# Javascript regexp creation error

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
aw_check_custom_validation['my-phone'] = /^\+[0-9]{1,3}(\s[0-9]{1,6}\s|\([0-9]{1,6}\)|[0-9]{1,6})[0-9\s]{5,8}$/u;
```

and I receive the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'u'
```

Why the /u flag causes this error?

Comment: what did you expect /u to do?

Comment: Because the only valid flags are `i`, `m` and `g`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the `/u` flag is PHP-specific, enabling Unicode support (which your regex isn't using anyway, unless you're planning on matching Unicode whitespace characters with the `\s` shorthand). Why not just remove it?

For reference, [JavaScript only supports](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) the `/g` (global matching), `/i` (case-insensitive matching) and `/m` (multiline, i. e. allow `^` and `$` to match at the start and end of each line) modifiers.

Comment: @32bitkid: Maybe, but JavaScript regexes are sorely lacking in Unicode support. Apart from individual code points (`\u1234`) there isn't much. `\w` only matches ASCII characters, for example; there is no support at for Unicode scripts/blocks/properties (`\p{L}` etc.) and so on...

Comment: @TimPietzcker what if i use `/` in `preview.replace(/\[ul\](.+)\[\/ul\]/mg, ul_list);` instead of `^` and `$`? `/m` doesn't work for it. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I'm sorry, can you answer me?

Comment: @flinth: I'm sorry, I don't see the connection to this question. If you want to ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button and include more information. The comments aren't suitable for this.

Comment: JavaScript support of the `u` flag is being added in ECMAScript 2015, so the `u` flag is available (and described in the documentation) for the RegExp constructor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp. Earliest browser versions supporting `u`: Chrome v.50, Firefox / Gecko v.46.

Answer (score 2):

It's a **highly** cryptic message that means that the `u` flag  you are passing to the RegEx constructor is invalid. JavaScript supports;

- `g` (global match)
- `m` ("Treat beginning and end characters (^ and $) as working over multiple lines")
- `i` (case insensitive match)

[For further info, see the MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: thx for explanation! I understand that I misunderstand regexp's flags:)

Comment: Currently (after some years of waiting), the `u` flag is available (and described in the documentation) for the RegExp constructor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp in browsers supporting ECMAScript 2015 (Chrome v.50, Firefox / Gecko v.46).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is your case or not, but I had similar issue with Node.js:

> SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'u'

I fixed it simply by updating Node.js in my Ubuntu server.
Previous version was:

```
$ node -v
v5.1.1
```

Then I did:

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
   ... long output
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
   ... shorter output
$ node -v
v6.7.0
```

And no more issues.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not a valid JavaScript regex flag; the valid flags are `g` (global), `i` (ignore case), and `m` (multiline).